# install air 2.6 apps on iOS simulator?

Tags: iphone, air, ios-simulator

Is it possible to test apps on the iOS simulator made with adobe air 2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator can only execute iOS app compiled in x86 (native for the mac), I think adobe air only give you an app compiled for iOS devices (ARM) and this kind of app can not be executed on the mac.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess compiling apps for the simulator would also be quite time consuming anyway, and adobes development time is better spent on device performance.